# Problem while trying to use tensorflow with repl-it

Tags: python, replit

I have this problem while using repl-it. Did someone have a similar problem or know how to solve that one?

```
Repl.it: Updating package configuration

--> python3 -m poetry add tensorflow
Using version ^2.4.1 for tensorflow

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...


Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing tensorflow (2.4.1)

[EnvCommandError]
Command ['/opt/virtualenvs/python3/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'tensorflow==2.4.1'] errored with the following return code -9, and output: 
Collecting tensorflow==2.4.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/9b/3fdbce9195fe53adbab1a930ee95a957af18c34a83ae5b1145f3cf8da409/tensorflow-2.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (394.4MB)

exit status 1


Repl.it: Package operation failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be already installed. Try importing again without adding to poetry